# Unable to access data passed by angular material dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular8

I have passed formarray values to angular material dialog. But while displaying I am getting this error: "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Array"

Here is my code

```
openDialog() {


this.purchase_id = ("purchase" + new Date().toISOString())

for(let i=0 ;i<this.product.value.length; i++) {


  let new_purchase : any = {
    purchase_id : this.purchase_id,
    quantity : this.product.value[i].product_quantity,
    buyingprice : this.product.value[i].product_Buyingprice,
    date : new Date(),
    product_id : Number (this.product.value[i].product_name),
    vendor_id : this.vendor_id,
    totalprice : String (this.product.value[i].product_quantity * this.product.value[i].product_Buyingprice)

  }


  const dialogRef =  this.dialog.open(ConfirmDialogComponent,{data : {purchase : new_purchase} })
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  console.log(`result : ${result}`)


  if(result == 'true') {

    this.newPurchase()

  }


})

}
```

}

dialog ts

```
`export class ConfirmDialogComponent implements OnInit {


  private savedForLater : any;


  constructor(
    public containingDialog: MatDialogRef<ConfirmDialogComponent>,

    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data : any)  { 

        this.savedForLater = data;

        console.log(this.savedForLater)


    }
`
```

dialog html

```
    <p>confirm-dialog works!</p>
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Details</h2>
<mat-dialog-content> 
        <div *ngFor = " let data of savedForLater"> 
                {{savedForLater.quantity}}
        </div>
</mat-dialog-content>


<mat-dialog-actions>


    <button mat-button mat-dialog-close mat-dialog-close = "false">log out</button>
    <button mat-button mat-dialog-close mat-dialog-close = "true">login</button>


</mat-dialog-actions>
```

[image] This is the data I have passed

Comment: Is `savedForLater` holds `array` data?
Its seems `ngFor` not recieving a data on which it can iterate.

```<div *ngFor = " let data of savedForLater"> 
                {{savedForLater.quantity}}
        </div>```
These statement doesn't make sense for angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to iterate object. It's not an Array. If you want to iterate object with `*ngFor` then use Angular's `keyvalue` pipe. See below :

```
<div *ngFor = " let data of savedForLater.purchase | keyvalue"> 
  {{data.key}} : {{data.value}}
</div>
```

You can print only value also.

```
<div *ngFor = " let data of savedForLater.purchase | keyvalue"> 
   {{data.value}}
</div>
```

Reference : https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe

Comment: Thankx for answer. Can your please answer this https://stackoverflow.com/q/58394836/7628381